# Need to select only those attribute values starting with "name" and conditional check

Tags: sql-server, xml

Please suggest on below XML data:

```
<data>
<x name="name0">val1</x>
<x name="other0">Yes</x>
<x name="name1">val2</x>
<x name="other1">Yes</x>
<x name="name2">val3</x>
<x name="other2">No</x>
<x name="name3">val4</x>
<x name="other3">No</x>
...
...
</data>
```

Need to select only those attribute values starting with "name" for 0,1,2,3... whose respective "other" values 0,1,2,3 are "Yes" ...end to end mapping on 0,1,2,3... for "name" & "other" based on "Yes" or "No"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an awfull design!

If the creation of this XML is under your control, you really should change this to something like

```
<data>
  <x val1="SomeName" val2="SomeOtherValue">
</data>
```

Doing so, you'd have the corresponding values together. **Avoid numbered column names!**
If you need this, do it like this

```
<data>
  <x val1="SomeName" Number="1" val2="SomeOtherValue">
</data>
```

Nevertheless your problem can be solved:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<data>
<x name="name0">val1</x>
<x name="other0">Yes</x>
<x name="name1">val2</x>
<x name="other1">Yes</x>
<x name="name2">val3</x>
<x name="other2">No</x>
<x name="name3">val4</x>
<x name="other3">No</x>
</data>';

WITH Shredded AS
(
    SELECT x.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS x_name
          ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',x.value('@name','nvarchar(max)')) AS PositionFirstNumber
          ,x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS x_value
    FROM @xml.nodes('/data/x') AS A(x)
)
,Splitted AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(x_name,PositionFirstNumber-1) AS columnName
          ,SUBSTRING(x_name,PositionFirstNumber,100) AS ColumnIndex
          ,x_value
    FROM Shredded
)
SELECT s1.x_value AS name_value
      ,(SELECT x_value FROM Splitted AS s2 WHERE s2.columnName='other' AND s1.ColumnIndex=s2.ColumnIndex) AS Corresponding_value

FROM Splitted AS s1 WHERE s1.columnName='name'
```

The result, which you might filter to any condition is

```
val1    Yes
val2    Yes
val3    No
val4    No
```

Comment: Yes this is bad xml but belongs to old codebase and cant be changed. thanks by the way, it works

Comment: @Satty: If the answer satisfies the requirements of your expected outcome, it would be considered polite on SO to accept it.